# Is there an equivalent of Haskell's `let`/`in` in C Preprocessor Macros?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I have a function as follows (used in a prime seive, in case you're curious)

```
unsigned long long primeAt(unsigned long long index) {
    return index * 3 + (index % 2 ? 2 : 1);
}
```

which I have refactored into the macro

```
#define PRIME_AT(index) (index * 3 + (index % 2 ? 2 : 1))
```

for performance and readability reasons.

I was wondering if there is any way to do the same for this function:

```
unsigned long long indexOf(unsigned long long prime) {
    int mod = prime % 6;
    return prime / 3 - (mod == 0 || mod == 3 || mod == 4);
}
```

without having to recalculate `prime % 6` 3 times as follows?

```
#define INDEX_OF(prime) (prime / 3 - ((prime % 6) == 0 || (prime % 6) == 3 || (prime % 6) == 4));
```

(This code will be run literally billions if not trillions of times so performance is paramount)

Comment: Please don't do that. There is no performance difference between macro and function (check an assembly listing for both https://goo.gl/440RXf). Compiler is smart enough to do such micro-optimizations for you. But if you ever write, for example, `INDEX_OF(myPrimeNumber + 1)`, you will be surprised.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could not be simply...

```
#define INDEX_OF(prime,mod) (prime / 3 - (mod == 0 || mod == 3 || mod == 4));
```

Comment: I can't believe how I missed that, such a simple elegant solution!

Comment: actually, it becomes even more elegant if you add a second macro that's just `INDEX_OF((prime), (prime%6))`

Answer (score 1):

It's not standard, but GCC (and all other compilers that emulate it, i.e. practically everything but MSVC) supports a thing called "statement expressions". In conjunction with a possible `typeof`, it can make macros very powerful.

```
#define MAX(a, b) ({ __typeof__((a)) __a = (a); typeof((b)) __b = (b); __a > __b ? __a : __b; })
```

The last statement in the `({})` block must be an expression statement, which will be used as the value of the statement expression.

That said, if `a` and `b` have provably no side effects, GCC is very good at optimizing away repeated calculations even without this.